# MySQL connection conflict with wildcard (any) user and host

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a weird user conflict on my MySQL server. 
I have 2 users. Actually I am stuck with the first wildcard user (Any user @ any host) and had to deny him all access for security :

```
╔══════╦══════════════╦══════════╦═══════════════════╦═══════╗
║ User ║     Host     ║ Password ║ Global privileges ║ Grant ║
╠══════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═══════════════════╬═══════╣
║ Any  ║ %            ║ No       ║ USAGE             ║ No    ║
║ root ║ 10.15.15.115 ║ No       ║ ALL PRIVILEGES    ║ Yes   ║
╚══════╩══════════════╩══════════╩═══════════════════╩═══════╝
```

The second one is the one I am using (forget about the fact he doesn't have password). When I try to connect `'root'@'10.15.15.115'`, MySQL says :

```
Access denied to ''@'%'
```

even though I am explicitly specifying to connect to `'root'@'10.15.15.115'`

Why is MySQL confusing with the first wildcard user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host field specifies the host you're connecting *from*, but my perception of what you wrote makes it sound like 10.15.15.115 is the server you're connecting *to*.

If MySQL can't match the username and host, it falls back to the anonymous user (when enabled), which looks like the problem here.

Based on the results you've shown, I'm not sure how you disabled the anonymous user, but I'm pretty sure the problem is that your host is not matching and as a result it's trying the anonymous user which you've disabled, causing the error message.

When setting up your user, remember that hosts `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, and `10.15.15.115` are all different connections, even if the connection is happening on the same machine you'll need to use the proper host value in order to connect.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to connect with?  I assume command line.  If so, does your connection attempt via command line look like this?

```
mysql -u root -h 10.15.15.115
```